# How to show data views oracle in C#

Tags: c#

I want to show data view oracle in datagridview by using C#, the data take from views oracle not from table.
I have tried with many ways, but it did not fix it. The data would not show in the datagridview. Now I don't have any idea how to fix it. Does anyone can help me to fix it this problem ?
Here is my coding program;

```
private void loadingData()
   {
       this.makeConnection();

       Console.WriteLine("\nBegin loading data...");

       try
       {
           OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM TMCI_ITM_DETAIL", connection); //TMCI_ITM_DETAIL take from views oracle not from table
           OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
           DataView table = new DataView();

           adapter.Fill(View);

           dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

           Console.WriteLine("Success loading data...");

           this.closeConnection();

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Failed to load data :: " + ex.Message);
       }
   }
```

Comment: What exactly happens when your code is run? Have you tried setting breakpoints in the code and verifying that the data has in fact been fetched?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try:

```
 private void loadingData()
   {
       this.makeConnection();

       Console.WriteLine("\nBegin loading data...");

       try
       {
           OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SELECT DISTINCT t1.ITM_CD, t1.ITM_NM, t1.UNIT_CD, t1.PCKG_UNIT_QTY, t1.PCKG_UNIT_CD, t1.MAIN_INP_CD, t1.HS_CD, t1.EXT_ITM_NM, t1.CTG_A, t1.CTG_B, t1.CTG_C, t1.CTG_D ,t1.CTG_E, t1.RMRKS02, t1.FLEX_NUM01, t1.FLEX_NUM03, t1.FLEX_NUM04, t1.FLEX_NUM05, T2.UNIT_WT, T3.C_INPT_QTY, T3.C_REQ_QTY, T3.P_REQ_QTY, T4.BOM_PTN, T4.PROD_LOC_CD FROM CM_HINMO_ALL t1 INNER JOIN CM_ITM_UNIT_ALL T2 ON T1.ITM_CD = T2.ITM_CD AND T1.UNIT_CD = T2.UNIT_CD LEFT JOIN SM_BOM_ALL T3 ON T1.ITM_CD = T3.P_ITM_CD LEFT JOIN SM_HINMOS_ALL T4 ON T1.ITM_CD = T4.ITM_CD WHERE 0=0 AND T3.BOM_PTN IN (1,2,3,4) ORDER BY ITM_CD", connection);
           OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
           DataTable table = new DataTable();

           adapter.Fill(table);

           dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

           dataGridView1.DataBind();

           Console.WriteLine("Success loading data...");

           this.closeConnection();

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Failed to load data :: " + ex.Message);
       }
   }
```

if this doesn't work try:

```
 private void loadingData()
   {
       this.makeConnection();

       Console.WriteLine("\nBegin loading data...");

       try
       {
           OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SELECT DISTINCT t1.ITM_CD, t1.ITM_NM, t1.UNIT_CD, t1.PCKG_UNIT_QTY, t1.PCKG_UNIT_CD, t1.MAIN_INP_CD, t1.HS_CD, t1.EXT_ITM_NM, t1.CTG_A, t1.CTG_B, t1.CTG_C, t1.CTG_D ,t1.CTG_E, t1.RMRKS02, t1.FLEX_NUM01, t1.FLEX_NUM03, t1.FLEX_NUM04, t1.FLEX_NUM05, T2.UNIT_WT, T3.C_INPT_QTY, T3.C_REQ_QTY, T3.P_REQ_QTY, T4.BOM_PTN, T4.PROD_LOC_CD FROM CM_HINMO_ALL t1 INNER JOIN CM_ITM_UNIT_ALL T2 ON T1.ITM_CD = T2.ITM_CD AND T1.UNIT_CD = T2.UNIT_CD LEFT JOIN SM_BOM_ALL T3 ON T1.ITM_CD = T3.P_ITM_CD LEFT JOIN SM_HINMOS_ALL T4 ON T1.ITM_CD = T4.ITM_CD WHERE 0=0 AND T3.BOM_PTN IN (1,2,3,4) ORDER BY ITM_CD", connection);
           OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
           DataTable table = new DataTable();

           adapter.Fill(table);

           dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns( 
            DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
           dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

           Console.WriteLine("Success loading data...");

           this.closeConnection();

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Failed to load data :: " + ex.Message);
       }
   }
```

Please follow: [How to: Bind Objects to Windows Forms DataGridView Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-objects-to-windows-forms-datagridview-controls)

And [How to: Bind Data to the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-data-to-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control)

Comment: I am sorry, I was wrong to copy paste the coding program. Here's the actual coding program that does not work in my my project.

OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM TMCI_ITM_DETAIL", connection); //TMCI_ITM_DETAIL take from views oracle not from table